# What are my options for allowing access from outside to my LAN file server?

Tags: nas

I have a fileserver at home with my music. I'd like to be able to access it when I'm not home. Should I explore NAS options?

Comment: I do not think this is a hardware recommendation since you already have a server...

Comment: Agreed, it sounds like you really just need help with software. I'd recommend looking into Wireguard for creating a VPN you can use to access your home network remotely, or maybe Nextcloud if you want something with a cute GUI.